# How to fix Table is upside down

Tags: html, css, html-table

I made a table in my .html file but after checking the page my table was upside down  ex my first row is the last row.

```css
#class-container {
 position: relative;
 width: 80%;
 top: 5%;
 margin: auto;
 background: white;
 padding-top: 100px;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="class-container">
  <table cellpadding="10px" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <th>
     <h1>
      Avantaje
     </h1>
    </th>
    <th>
     <h1>
      Dezavantaje
     </h1>
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <ul type="square">
     <li>
      <h2>
       Consumul redus
      </h2>
     </li>
     <li>
      <h2>
       Poluarea aproape de zero in afara productiei
      </h2>
     </li>
     <li>
      <h2>
       Eficienta/randament foarte mare
      </h2>
     </li>
     <li>
      <h2>
       Accelerare instanta
      </h2>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

And the funny thing is that I have another table in another .html file whith the same div and I don't have a problem with that table
I browsed the web but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: I dont think this is valid HTML

Comment: @Pytth why do you think so? the code is like this because of my editor

Comment: that's not a valid html markup for table, `ul` is not a child of `tr`, you should use `td` and inside of that put your `ul`

Comment: @JuanCastillo thanks I just noticed 1 minute ago but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your `ul` in a `td` which should put the headers up back where you expect them.

```css
#class-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  top: 5%;
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="class-container">
  <table cellpadding="10px" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h1>
          Avantaje
        </h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1>
          Dezavantaje
        </h1>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul type="square">
          <li>
            <h2>
              Consumul redus
            </h2>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h2>
              Poluarea aproape de zero in afara productiei
            </h2>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h2>
              Eficienta/randament foarte mare
            </h2>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h2>
              Accelerare instanta
            </h2>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll mark it as the right answer after I'll be able to. This happens when I'm not carefully, I forget a tag and nothing works anymore :))